# How to stop excel from changing formulas within cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Actual/Estimated Ship Units Forecast",'WD ALPS'!$A:$K,MATCH(Date1,'WD ALPS'!$A$651:$K$651,0),FALSE),"")`
Each time I run a macro to re-pull the data referenced in this formula, excel changes the range by one. (which messes up all of my calculations.)
So I go from `MATCH(Date1,'WD ALPS'!$A$651:$K$651,0)` to `MATCH(Date1,'WD ALPS'!$A$650:$K$650,0)`
without reason. I want it to stay constant no matter what happens to the data sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use OFFSET. This is a volatile function, which may result in response time issues, but at a small scale, it is usually not an issue.

You would lock the OFFSET to an anchor cell that is not changed by the macro that you run.  In this case, I will assume A1 is not impacted.  You could change your formula to:

```
MATCH(Date1,OFFSET('WD ALPS'!$A$1,650,0):OFFSET('WD ALPS'!$A$1,650,10),0)
```

Another way that would not be volatile and would not have a dependency on an anchor would be to use INDEX in the same way:

```
MATCH(Date1,INDEX('WD ALPS'!$1:$1048576,651,1):INDEX('WD ALPS'!$1:$1048576,651,11),0)
```

This selects the whole sheet and then cuts out the piece that you want with absolute, fixed indices. The down side is that it evaluates the whole sheet -  I am not sure which would run faster.

Comment: Hey Mark, Thank you for the response! I tried running the formula with that added in, now it is editing it to give some sort Reference error.
 `MATCH(Date1,OFFSET('WD ALPS'!#REF!,650,0):OFFSET('WD ALPS'!#REF!,650,10)`
I wonder why it's deciding to edit anyway.

Comment: Wow! Super frustrating! Did you try INDEX?  btw - I had a typo in INDEX. I will fix it now.

Comment: Thank you! Using INDEX worked just fine. I really need to look more into Index/Match. Once again, I appreciate the help!